# Pass local docker image in Docker Golang SDK imagePull method

Tags: docker, go

I want to pull a docker image from my local system.

Image name is : example

```
import (

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    
)

cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

imageName := "example:latest"

out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

current code is giving me something like this :

```
panic: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for example, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Is it possble to pass local docker image to this method, if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can build image locally with tag 'localhost/example:latest'

```sh
 
  $ docker build -t "localhost/example:latest" .
```

Than, you can prepend `localhost` to image name, so it will try local registry to pull image, so, you can try this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
   
)


func main(){
  cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv,   client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
  if err != nil {
      panic(err)
  }

  imageName := "localhost/example:latest" // <- localhost prepended!

  out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, one should also include the `:port` part as per "When the first part of the tag is a hostname and port..." from https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#copy-an-image-from-docker-hub-to-your-registry

Comment: Solution that worked for me : I created a docker registry on local and mapped it with localhost:<some_port>
and then I was able to pass image name as :
<registry_url>/example:latest